# Reduce a 2D grid by minimizing number of Blackbox calls using any efficient algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a 2D grid of **100 × 100** points (total: 10000 points). X varies from 0 to 99 and Y varies 
from 0 to 99. I send each (x,y) to a **BlackBox module** and get back 2 values **p and q**. Blackbox 
essentially selects a function from its set of availble functions based on (x,y) and applies it 
on (x,y) then gives back **a cost and the function index it used**.

Thus Each point in this 2 dimensional space is associated with 2 values (p,q). First value **'p' says which function is used** by Blackbox and Second value **'q' is cost**. Function used by Blackbox for each (x,y) can differ and assume there are **at max V functions** that can be used by Blackbox**(V = ~60)**. Assume also that **cost is monotonically non-decreasing** in both **X and Y** dimensions.

Note that we can also call Blackbox with three arguments (x,y,k) which makes it execute function k on (x,y) and return some (k,q).

What I want to achieve is this. Blackbox chooses very high number of functions. **I want to reduce this by allowing little increase in cost of points**.

What I want to do is reduction of number of functions used in the grid. Say Blackbox has used all 60 functions at some points in the space. I want to find a minimal set of functions which when used to 
evaluate a point (x,y) will not increase cost of that point (x,y) by more than a factor 's'.

Ex.: Say factor 's' = 20%. Say I start from (99,99) and check its p. say p = 5 (5th function) 
at that point and q = 3000. Say at point (99,98), (p,q) = (8, 2600). I call Blackbox (99,98,5) 
which makes blackbox execute function 5 at point (99,98) and gets me say (8,2800) as return 
value. Though 2800 > 2600, 2800 - 2600 is within 20% of 2600, so since I can use function 5 of 
(99,99) at (99,98) also I can ignore function 8 atleast for point (99,98).

Like wise I want to **reduce the number of functions** used in the space to lower value without 
increasing cost of any point by more than 's'. What is the optimum way of doing this by calling **Blackbox minimum number of times**?

Bruteforce way: Choose each distinct function used and evaluate it throughout space and based on that decide which is the minimum set of functions covering all points in the space with 's' threshold satified.

I know this question is really difficult to read but I have tried the best I can to ask my 
question precisely.

Comment: It seems that "the cost is monotonically non-decreasing in both directions" holds only for the "combined" function, and that the individual functions (e.g. function 5 in your example) need not obey that property.  If so, the problem is impossible to solve exactly with fewer than 10000 function evaluations, since you need at least 1 function in your cover, and it might be arbitrarily bad at any point you don't evaluate it at.  You need extra conditions on the 60 individual BB functions to do better.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Individual functions obey that property independently

Comment: Assuming that you meant to write "I call Blackbox (99,98,5) which makes blackbox execute function 5 at point (99,98) and gets me say (**5**,3100) as return value.", this clearly doesn't hold for function 5, since 3100 > 3000 but 98 < 99.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I meant to say that if you evaluate the same function throughout space you will be able to see monotonicity..I will correct this mistake in the example I gave

Comment: @j_random_hacker: cost depends on two things. which function you use and at which point (x,y) you use it. Blackbox chooses best function to use for a (x,y) which has least cost. But I am saying I dont want to use best function for (x,y) at (x,y). Its enough for me if I can assure that I wont increase cost(x,y) by more than 's' by another function in the space so that I get I cover entire space by least number of unique functions

Comment: Right, my previous comment was a misunderstanding -- I've deleted it now.

Comment: why this question is down voted by someone? If question is wrong or does not show research effort you can comment about it, atleast after downvoting

Answer (score 2):

Optimization is only possible if it's hugely expensive to call the black box with three arguments, e.g. the black box is only accessible across a network connection, so that the local machine can do 1000's of operation in the time that it takes to get one answer from the black box.

In that case, the optimization that I see is that you can make inferences about the value of each function at a given point using the monotonicity property of the functions.  This allows you to call the functions at disperse locations in the grid and then "fill in the blanks" as it were.

For example, let's say I evaluate function 5 at locations {0,0} {0,4} {4,0} {4,4} and get the following results

```
 7 ? ? ? 9
 ? ? ? ? ?
 ? ? ? ? ?
 ? ? ? ? ?
 3 ? ? ? 5
```

Then I can infer that the worst case values for function 5 are

```
 7 9 9 9 9
 7 9 9 9 9
 7 9 9 9 9
 7 9 9 9 9
 3 5 5 5 5
```

and I can infer that the best case values for function 5 are

```
 7 7 7 7 9
 3 3 3 3 5 
 3 3 3 3 5
 3 3 3 3 5 
 3 3 3 3 5
```

Taking this technique to the extreme, you could evaluate each function using x and y values of 0, 50, and 99. This will divide the overall space into 4 regions, and the information gleaned can be used to start culling the list of useful functions.  For example, if the *worst case* value for function 33 in region 1 is 100, and the *best case* value for function 45 in region 1 is 150, then function 45 can be removed from consideration in region 1.

After culling the list of useful functions, divide each region into four subregions by evaluating the remaining functions at the midpoint.  Continue subdividing as necessary. Eventually, either a single function will dominate an entire region, or the region will be reduced to a single point with a limited number of candidate functions remaining.

You can also start by consulting the black box for the best possible value at each point by calling the black box using two arguments (x,y).  Then apply the fudge factor 's' to find the absolute maximum value for every point in the grid.  As you subdivide the grid, you can eliminate functions whose best case value is greater than the absolute maximum. For example, if the absolute maximum is 200 at point {20,22}, and the best case value for function 5 at point {20,22} is 210, then function 5 can be removed from consideration at point {20,22}.